# Disable Airplay on Mac because of too many Airplay devices

Tags: macos, network, airplay, bonjour

I'd like to find a solution to my problem. I recently moved to a dorm of around 1100 students, and each one of these students has a mediabox that is also an Airplay device.

Because of this, the Airplay service seems to completely destroy the sound on the client and make it very slow. I've worked around this by just disabling bonjour altogether by unloading the mDNSResponder and mDNSResponderHelper plists from the launch daemons, but this also makes the multicast announcements of my IPTV service fail.

I've tried blocking the bonjour packets to no success either (with Littlesnitch).

I'd just like it to not load the Airplay devices at all, so it doesn't get hogged up with them.

Information about my system: OSX 10.9.3 (on both a Macbook and an iMac). 
Things I've tried:

1. Chmodding the mDNSService to 000 (doesn't work that well)
2. Blocking the ports associated with Airplay announcements (5353)
3. Completely unloading the mDNSResponder and mDNSResponderHelper

I'm connected through a wired network, and the announcements are sent via multicast announcements (as with my IPTV).

Answer (score 4):

Try Disable AirPlay Mirroring in your terminal

```
sudo chmod 000 

/System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPlayUIAgent
```

To turn it back on

```
sudo chmod 755 

/System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPlayUIAgent
```

Here is the list of Ports used by Airplay

[image: airplay ports]

[source](http://www.ehcho.com/guide/disable-airplay-mirroring/)

Comment: OSX 10.11 as root: `chmod: Unable to change file mode on /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPlayUIAgent: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @gcb - In El Capitan, SIP is getting in the way of executing this command.

Answer (score 1):

AirPlayXPCHelper `/usr/libexec/AirPlayXPCHelper` was hammering port 7000 on my local network.  Port 7000 is not documented in Apple's who's who of ports and usage:

```
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944
```

I found it using a light duty application network access monitoring and application firewall software package called Radio Silence.

Radio Silence is an all or nothing easy interface for process network access monitoring. https://radiosilenceapp.com. For those that find Little Snitch or HandsOff! a little too complex or overwhelming in the settings, this is a quick and dirty tool with a clean interface.

Comment: Same, `AirPlayXPCHelper` was hammering port 7000 on a strange IP in the assigned range (192.168.86.173).  I reinstalled the OS from scratch and was still hammering port 7000 on the same strange assigned internal IP.  I found it using Wireshark and then used `netstat -anvt | grep SYN_SENT` when it was trying to connect to give me a PID and then `ps -ax | grep $PID` to find that it was `AirPlayXPCHelper`.