# MacOs with High Sierra problem persistant after fresh reinstall

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra

My wifi card is trying to make a connection to a seemingly random IP address on the local network. The Mac Mini 2011 is connected to the local network via Wifi. I completed a fresh re-install of MacOS High Sierra from USB and the wifi card still tries to make this connection.

Packet capture of network traffic with Wireshark shows that the network card is calling out roughly every 1 minute 30 seconds, attempting to make a connection to an IP on the local network (192.168.86.173, Port 7000) by sending a SYN packet. Then several re-transmissions of the SYN take place, since there is no response from the IP the client is trying to reach.

I have ping and nmap the IP 192.168.86.173, but no response. I have used network scanner and no device shows on that IP.

I looked up port 7000 and only found a file-server that uses UDP, not TCP. (https://www.auditmypc.com/tcp-port-7000.asp), and something called Gryphon for automobile testing that uses TCP (http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip/ports07000.htm).

Does anyone know what is causing this?  Why would this be persistent after a fresh reinstall?

Comment: You should be able to find out what process is trying to make a connection with `udo lsof -i:7000`. Also, if it's sending SYN packets, something must be responding to ARP; try `arp 192.168.86.173` and see what you get. BTW, what exactly do you mean by a "fresh reinstall"?

Comment: By fresh reinstall I mean a full reinstall after erasing the drive and by using time machine backups or without erasing the drive.

Comment: I tracked the process down using command `netstat -anvt | grep SYN_SENT` and found the PID.  I checked the PID using `ps -ax | grep $PID`.  That resolved to `AirPlayXPCHelper`.  Now I'm wondering why `AirPlayXPCHelper` checks that particular IP address. Answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217253/little-snitch-reports-outgoing-connections-for-airplayxpchelper-for-wrong-subnet

Comment: I'm not on a CIDR /24 network.  I'm on a CIDR /16.  So, the address it's checking is on the LAN.   However, I'm still curious why that particular address since it was persistent after a complete reinstall.